# Passing conditional data between 2 sheets (Google sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Here's my situation:
I have sheet 1 (Basic Wizard) that has cells in it with "Pass/Fail" conditions. (if Pass - cell displays Pass and turns green. if Fail - cell displays Fail and turns red.)
I also have sheet 2 (Traceability) with "Pass/Fail" cell.
What I would like to do is:
When ALL cells in sheet 1 are "Pass", then cell in sheet 2 automatically shows "Pass"
If 1 (of any) fails in sheet 1, then cell in sheet 2 automatically shows "Fail"

[Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N95Ru.png)
[Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75fx3.png)

Using google to find an answer I was given some formulas to create the rule, however, it seems like I am misunderstanding the instructions and my rules do not work. Something along the lines of:
sheet 1 (Basic Wizard) =COUNTIF('Basic Wizard'!E24:E51,E22,E53:E54,E56:E60,E62:E66,E68:E74,E77)=COLUMNS('Traceability'!E7)
sheet 2 (Traceability) =IF(AND('Basic Wizard!E24:E51,E22,E53:E54,E56:E60,E62:E66,E68:E74,E77='Pass'),TRUE,FALSE)

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you may want to try: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the highlighted cell shown in your Sheet 2 image:

```
=IF(COUNTIF('Basic Wizard'!$E$22:$E,"FAIL")>0,"FAIL","PASS")
```

Leaving the range open-ended (note the last `$E` does not have a number after it in the range `$E$22:$E`) and checking for the word `"FAIL"` means you don't have to provide all those specifically chunked ranges.

This should achieve your desired result without any other helper formulas, but let me know if you run into any issues.

Comment: @Pavel Vagner did this end up working for you?

Comment: @Adrian_Mole I know the guidelines advise we strictly answer the question and avoid addressing the asker, but do we really feel that removing small asides of encouragement like “hope that helps!” improves the  vibes and fosters a welcoming community where people feel comfortable being a bit vulnerable while asking for help in a public forum?